# APK file creation

Tags: apk, construct-3

I have created a sample game using construct 3 . I want to know how can I convert it in apk file . I have no idea about that . Do I need to do it on Android Studio ?
Can any one help me please .
Many thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can create an APK by exporting the project for Android and then Import that project in Android studio and build it.